# Any way to generate fully initialized constructor automatically by Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, constructor, code-generation

Using `Eclipse`
For any `Class` we can automatically

- Generate Setters an Getters
- Generate Delegate Methods
- Generate hashCode() and equals()
- Generate toString()
- Generate Constructor using Fields
- Generate Constructor From Superclass

Like that
[image]

Any way to generate
`Fully initialized Constructor`
(Constructor `without` any parameters that initialized all non-primitive fields)
For example
If my class as that

```
public class MyClass {

    private String id;
    private String code;
    private MyClass1 myClass1;
    private MyClass2 myClass2;

}
```

Generated Fully initialized Constructor will be

```
public class MyClass {

    private String id;
    private String code;
    private MyClass1 myClass1;
    private MyClass2 myClass2;

    // Fully initialized Constructor    
    public FlightScheduleRequest() {
        this.myClass1 = new MyClass1();
        this.myClass2 = new MyClass2();
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens MyClass1 does not have the default constructor, but takes 3 arguments?

Comment: @Jayan very very good note

Comment: Probably a good start : http://projectlombok.org/features/index.html

Comment: Moreover, allocating instance in your constructors makes testing hard (See Inversion of Dependencies). Now, if Eclipse could generate a constructor that takes 3 args and assigns them to 3 member vars, I'd be cheering right along with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its invalid requirement**

Thanks to @Jayan note
If `MyClass1` or `MyClass2` does not have the default constructor,
but takes arguments for its constructor
So the initialization of them will be invalid

```
this.myClass1 = new  MyClass1(); // The constructor MyClass1() is undefined
this.myClass2 = new  MyClass2(); // The constructor MyClass2() is undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an option there to generate constructor using fields. 
Select the fields which you want the initialization for and you are done.

Comment: "Generate constructor using fields" creates constructor with arguments, not unparameterized constructor with initialized fields.